# How can I access an object attribute that starts with a number?

Tags: php, object

I'm working on an existing code base and got back an object with an attribute that starts with a number, which I can see if I call `print_r` on the object.

Let's say it's `$Beeblebrox->2ndhead`. When I try to access it like that, I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

How can I get that attribute?

Comment: I know that you work on existing code, but for the sake of completeness I want to add, that one should avoid using variables that enforces to use the curly bracket syntax. "Normal" use of variables names is just better known and easier to read.

Comment: I just [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/50079) a similar question; if you are having problems with an attribute that is **all numbers** you will find the solution there.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What about this :

```
$Beeblebrox->{'2ndhead'}
```

Actually, you can do this for pretty much any kind of variable -- even for ones that are not class properties.

For example, you could think about a variable's name that contains spaces ; the following syntax will work :

```
${"My test var"} = 10;
echo ${"My test var"};
```

Even if, obviously, you would not be able to do anything like this :

```
$My test var = 10;
echo $My test var;
```

No idea how it's working internally, though... And after a bit of searching, I cannot find anything about this in the PHP manual.

Only thing I can find about `{}` and variables is in here : [Variable parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) -- but not quite related to the current subject...

But here's an article that shows a couple of other possiblities, and goes farther than the examples I posted here : [**PHP Variable Names: Curly Brace Madness**][2]

And here's another one that gives some additionnal informations about the way those are parsed : [**PHP grammar notes**](http://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/php-grammar-notes/)

Comment: Yep - that's it! You answered before I could! :)

Comment: If you want to elaborate on why this works and is needed (maybe you know more than I do?), that would make this page more useful and interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know why this works -- I just know it does ^^ *(Still, I've edited my answer to give a bit more informations)*

Answer (score 6):

I actually found out the answer from a coworker before I asked this, but couldn't find it on Google, so I wanted to post it here in case others have the same problem.

I can access that attribute like so:

```
$Beeblebrox->{'2ndhead'}
```

It's not really legal to have an attribute or variable that begins with a number, but somehow a dynamic reference like this makes it possible. Seems like a weird loophole in the language to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this too:

```
$aux = '2ndhead';
$Beeblebrox->$aux;
```