# How can I access object properties with names like integers or invalid property names?

Tags: php, object, properties

I am using `json_decode()`, something like:

```
$myVar = json_decode($data)
```

Which gives me output like this:

```
[highlighting] => stdClass Object
        (
            [448364] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Tax amount liability is .......
```

I want to access the string value in the key [0]. When I try to do something like:

```
print $myVar->highlighting->448364->Data->0;
```

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER

The two numerals/integers there seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 313, accepted):

## Updated for PHP 7.2

PHP 7.2 introduced a behavioral change to [converting numeric keys in object and array casts](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/convert_numeric_keys_in_object_array_casts), which fixes this particular inconsistency and makes all the following examples behave as expected.

One less thing to be confused about!

---

## Original answer (applies to versions earlier than 7.2.0)

PHP has its share of dark alleys that you *really* don't want to find yourself inside. Object properties with names that are numbers is one of them...

### What they never told you

**Fact #1:** You cannot access properties with names that are not legal variable names easily

```
$a = array('123' => '123', '123foo' => '123foo');
$o = (object)$a;
echo $o->123foo; // error
```

**Fact #2:** You *can* access such properties with curly brace syntax

```
$a = array('123' => '123', '123foo' => '123foo');
$o = (object)$a;
echo $o->{'123foo'}; // OK!
```

**Fact #3:** But *not* if the property name is all digits!

```
$a = array('123' => '123', '123foo' => '123foo');
$o = (object)$a;
echo $o->{'123foo'}; // OK!
echo $o->{'123'}; // error!
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/sn119).

**Fact #4:** Well, unless the object didn't come from an array in the first place.

```
$a = array('123' => '123');
$o1 = (object)$a;
$o2 = new stdClass;
$o2->{'123'} = '123'; // setting property is OK

echo $o1->{'123'}; // error!
echo $o2->{'123'}; // works... WTF?
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/ZxVSZ).

Pretty intuitive, don't you agree?

### What you can do

**Option #1: do it manually**

The most practical approach is simply to cast the object you are interested in back into an array, which will allow you to access the properties:

```
$a = array('123' => '123', '123foo' => '123foo');
$o = (object)$a;
$a = (array)$o;
echo $o->{'123'}; // error!
echo $a['123']; // OK!
```

Unfortunately, this does not work recursively. So in your case you 'd need to do something like:

```
$highlighting = (array)$myVar->highlighting;
$data = (array)$highlighting['448364']->Data;
$value = $data['0']; // at last!
```

**Option #2: the nuclear option**

An alternative approach would be to write a function that converts objects to arrays recursively:

```
function recursive_cast_to_array($o) {
    $a = (array)$o;
    foreach ($a as &$value) {
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $value = recursive_cast_to_array($value);
        }
    }

    return $a;
}

$arr = recursive_cast_to_array($myVar);
$value = $arr['highlighting']['448364']['Data']['0'];
```

However, I 'm not convinced that this is a better option across the board because it will needlessly cast to arrays all of the properties that you are *not* interested in as well as those you are.

**Option #3: playing it clever**

An alternative of the previous option is to use the built-in JSON functions:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($myVar), true);
$value = $arr['highlighting']['448364']['Data']['0'];
```

The JSON functions helpfully perform a recursive conversion to array without the need to define any external functions. However desirable this looks, it has the "nuke" disadvantage of option #2 *and additionally* the disadvantage that if there is any strings inside your object, those strings *must* be encoded in UTF-8 (this is a requirement of [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Comment: **Fact #0**: Casting arrays into objects shouldn't make no stinky sense in the first place. Fact #1 to Fact #3: unneeded.

Comment: @Pacerier: I agree that it's somewhat questionable, but it can totally make sense in some situations. Anyway, since it's [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) in the manual to work like this, our personal opinions don't really matter.

Comment: An alternative to Option #3 that doesn't require UTF-8 would be `$o = unserialize('O:8:"StdClass"' . substr(serialize($a),1));`

Comment: Great answer! In the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) it is stated **An array converts to an object with properties named by keys ..  with the exception of numeric keys which will be inaccessible __unless iterated__**. What is ment with **unless iterated**? Is there another way how one could access these numbers?

Answer (score 11):

I just wanted to add to [Jon's eloquent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-can-i-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers-or-invalid-property/10333200#10333200) the reason why this fails. It's all because when creating an array, PHP converts keys to integers — if it can — which causes lookup problems on arrays which have been cast to objects, simply because the numeric key is preserved. This is problematic because all property access options expect or convert to strings. You can confirm this by doing the following:

```
$arr = array('123' => 'abc');
$obj = (object) $arr;
$obj->{'123'} = 'abc';
print_r( $obj );
```

Which would output:

```
stdClass Object (
  [123] => 'abc',
  [123] => 'abc'
)
```

So the object has two property keys, one numeric (which can't be accessed) and one string based. This is the reason why Jon's `#Fact 4` works, because by setting the property using curly braces means you always define a string-based key, rather than numeric.

Taking Jon's solution, but turning it on its head, you can generate an object from your array that always has string-based keys by doing the following:

```
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($arr));
```

From now on you can use either of the following because access in this manner always converts the value inside the curly brace to a string:

```
$obj->{123};
$obj->{'123'};
```

Good old illogical PHP...

Answer (score 5):

*For PHP 7*

Accessing Object properties having numbers as the property name.

It is mostly needed after casting an array to object.

```php
    $arr = [2,3,7];
    $o = (object) $arr;

    $t = "1";
    $t2 = 1;
    $t3 = (1);

    echo $o->{1};     // 3
    echo $o->{'1'};   // 3
    echo $o->$t;      // 3
    echo $o->$t2;     // 3
    echo $o->$t3;     // 3

    echo $o->1;       // Error
    echo $o->(1);     // Error
```

Answer (score 3):

A final alternative to [Jon's comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-can-i-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers-or-invalid-property/10333200#10333200):

Simply use *json_decode()* with the second parameter set to **true**.

```
$array = json_decode($url, true);
```

This then returns an associative array rather than an object, so there isn't any need to convert after the fact.

This may not be suitable to every application, but it really helped me to easily reference a property of the original object.

The solution was found in the tutorial *[Handling JSON like a boss in PHP](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP/)*.

Answer (score 2):

If an object begins with `@` like:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [@attributes] => Array (
        [href] => qwertyuiop.html
        [id] => html21
        [media-type] => application/xhtml+xml
    )
)
```

You have to use:

```
print_r($parent_object->attributes());
```

because `$parent_object->{'@attributes'}` or `$parent_object['@attributes']` won't work.

Comment: 3 years later and this is still helping people, thanks! While your answer fixes my issue it does lack an explanation. Is anyone able to explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you aren't allowed to name objects starting with numerics. Rename the first one "448364" starting with a letter.

The second one is an array, and those are to be accessed by brackets like so:

```
print myVar->highlighting->test_448364->Data[0]
```

instead

Comment: I cannot change it. The output is returned from an application of which I have no control.

Answer (score 0):

I had copied this function from the Internet. If it works as it says ("Function to Convert stdClass Objects to Multidimensional Arrays"), try the following:

```
<?php

    function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }

?>
```

- first pass your array to `objectToArray` function
- then take the return value
- echo `[highlighting][448364][Data][0]`

Source: [PHP stdClass to Array and Array to stdClass](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)

Comment: That source is [dodgy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dodgy#Adjective). They pump out a steady stream of low-quality content on the Internet. Is it some kind of [content farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_farm)? Using some kind of auto generation (auto plagiarising?) of content? From the difference in writing style, it is very clear ***they did not write those code comments themselves.*** Where were the code comments (and also the code?) copied from? Does that particular page have any merit? Does it actually work?