# Special characters in property name of object

Tags: php, syntax

If I have an object that contains a property that starts with a % symbol, how can I get its value.

If I use

```
echo $myobject->%myproperty;
```

I get an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE
```

I know I shouldn't use % in variable names, but it wasn't my doing and I'm stuck with it.

Comment: Related: [How to access object properties with names like integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
echo $myobject->{'%myproperty'};
```

Comment: Five years old, but still a bad answer, just one line of code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I don't disagree with you.  You should post your own answer with what you were going to edit into mine.

Comment: No, because the solution is the exact same, I just added some description.  This is worse than a _Try this_ `codez` answer.

Comment: May 2018 and this answer is still great. Thanks, no need to add further info, this is crystal clear as it is.

Comment: Trying to access '@attributes' property of a SimpleXMLElement object but it doesnt work. Had to convert object to array to make it work. Weird behaviour.

Comment: 2021 and the answer is still a great. No comment needed for one line of code with one term in it.

Works with Twitter endpoints such as

$rate_limits->resources->users->{'/users/'}

and even with

$rate_limits->resources->users->{'/users/:id'}

with its slashes and a colon.

Comment: @sba To get at attributes of an XML tag, you can use the string value of the attribute as an index. 
<url href="xyz.com">
$item->url['href']

Comment: Great answer! The less said the better, good code should speak for itself and not need comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more solution to convert object to an array, so that you will not get an error.

I have a symbol - on the object index, so I have used the above solution and got success.

```
$array = (array) $yourObject;
```

**Reference:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php