# How do I parse a PHP object when the attribute name is *?

Tags: php, object, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Special characters in property name of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455775/special-characters-in-property-name-of-object)

I'm parsing a JSON response from MediaWiki's API: [Requested URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=George%20Washington)

I run it through `json_decode()` and then pull some pieces of it.  The problem I have is that the attribute name for the content is `*`.  I get a PHP error when I try to access the content ( the 140,950 character string at the end of my vardumped json_decoded example below ) like this:

```
foreach( $Response->query->pages as $page_id => $Page ) {
    $this->id                   = $Page->pageid;
    $this->title                = $Page->title;
    $this->content_with_markup  = $Page->revisions[0]->*;
}
```

The PHP Error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*'`

The `pageid` and `title` work fine.

Here is the piece of JSON_Decoded object that is giving me problems:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["11968"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (4) {
    ["pageid"]=>
    int(11968)
    ["ns"]=>
    int(0)
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "George Washington"
    ["revisions"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
        ["contentformat"]=>
        string(11) "text/x-wiki"
        ["*"]=>
        string(140950) "{{About|the first President of the United States|other uses}}...
```

**How do I access the content contained in the attribute named *?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same as always.

```
...->{'*'}->...
```