# PHP Parsing json decoded result from wikipedia api MediaWiki

Tags: php, categories, json, mediawiki-api

I am trying to use the wikipedia mediawiki api to get a page data. The query url is :

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Nirnayam_%281991_film%29

One of the properties returned is categories:

```
"categories":[{"sortkey":"","*":"Telugu-language_films"},{"sortkey":"","*":"1991_films"},{"sortkey":"","*":"Indian_films"}]
```

A var_dump after json_decode  :

```
foreach($wiki_page_data_json->parse->categories as $cat)
{
    var_dump($cat);
}
```

gives me this :

> object(stdClass)[21]   public 'sortkey' => string '' (length=0)
>   public '*' => string 'Telugu-language_films' (length=21)
>
> object(stdClass)[22]   public 'sortkey' => string '' (length=0)
>   public '*' => string '1991_films' (length=10)
>
> object(stdClass)[23]   public 'sortkey' => string '' (length=0)
>   public '*' => string 'Indian_films' (length=12)

I can access public 'sortkey' as **$cat->sortkey**

Question is - **How do I access the value in public '*' ?**

Comment: Sorted ! I found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078453/how-do-i-parse-a-php-object-when-the-attribute-name-is?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access object properties with names that contain special characters using this notation:

```
foreach($wiki_page_data_json->parse->categories as $cat)
{
    var_dump( $cat->{'*'} );
}
```

Interesting reading > https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/67332

Answer (score 2):

You should probably make `json_decode()` only return arrays, and not arrays and objects.

```
json_decode($jsonstring, true); // last parameter true will return only arrays
```

Then it is easy:

```
$cat['sortkey'];
$cat['*'];
```

I don't really like objects to have inaccessible property names.