# Dealing with special characters in object property names

Tags: php, oop

I am working with a database created by a university professor's intern.  Many of the fields have names like 'Revenues_(budget)'.

Currently when working with objects that have the fields as properties I do something like

```
$f = 'Revenues_(budget)';
echo $obj->$f;
```

This works fine but I was wondering if there might be a more elegant or at least concise way to handle these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special characters in property name of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455775/special-characters-in-property-name-of-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in one expression:

```
echo $obj->{'Revenues_(budget)'};
```