# Parse nested JSON in php

Tags: php, json, decode

I am trying to decode JSON string as follows-

```
<?php
    $data = '{"hrm.com": { "a": "1",  "b": "c"  }}';
    $character = json_decode($data);
    $character = json_decode($character->hrm.com);
    echo $character->a;
?>
```

I am getting the error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$hrm
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special characters in property name of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455775/special-characters-in-property-name-of-object)

Comment: Have you tried without the dot in `htm.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
<?php
    $data = '{"hrm.com": { "a": "1",  "b": "c"  }}';
    $character = json_decode($data,true);
    echo $character['hrm.com']['a'];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

One single `json_decode` is enough:

```
$character = json_decode($data);

echo $character->{'hrm.com'}->a;
```

Or you can use the second parameter of the `json_decode` function to return an associative array:

```
$character = json_decode($data, true);

echo $character['hrm.com']['a'];
```