# PHP Please tell me how to access the Object key

Tags: php

```php
[zzcrewssadd] => stdClass Object
(
  [items] => stdClass Object
  (
    [item] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => abc
            [@0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [no] => 1
                    [id] => 01_00_00_00_00
                    [depth] => 1
                    [itemCnt] => 126647
                )

            [1] => def
            [@1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [no] => 2
                    [id] => 01_01_00_00_00
                    [depth] => 2
                    [itemCnt] => 37119
                )

            [2] => ghi
            [@2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [no] => 3
                    [id] => 01_01_01_00_00
                    [depth] => 3
                    [itemCnt] => 13730
                )
        )
  ) 
)
```

How do I approach it?

The code I tried.

**zzcrewssadd->items->item[@0];**

This will result in an error.
This will result in an error.
This will result in an error.
This will result in an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special characters in property name of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455775/special-characters-in-property-name-of-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you run a `foreach` loop on this `zzcrewssadd->items->item`

or try this to access object keys

`echo zzcrewssadd->items->item->{'@0'};`