# Looping through a multidimensional stdclass object and array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, stdclass

Been trying to figure this out for a while now, but can't seem to get it right. I'm working on an app that calls to an API and decodes a JSON response. I have the data, but I can not "work" with. Here is the data:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [custom_fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Heading 1
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => sub_1-1
                            [caption] => SubHeading 1-1
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => sub_1-2
                            [caption] => SubHeading 1-2
                        )
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Heading 2 
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => sub_2-1
                            [caption] => SubHeading 2-1
                        )
                )
        )
    [status] => 200
    [version] => 1.3.2
)
```

What I'm essentially trying to do is setup a table with Heading 1 then the 2 sub headings. I can get Heading 1 using `$APIRESULT->custom_fields->name` but I can not get the sub-headings. I'm sure it's easy and I'm just having a block, but I'm given up and hoping someone on here can help me real quick.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties with names like integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, variables cannot start with a digit, so you have to access it this way:

```
$APIRESULT->custom_fields->{'0'}->name // Access name

$APIRESULT->custom_fields->{'1'}->caption // Access something else
```

The solution should work, however I dislike the structure of that data as in my opinion `arrays` should be used instead of objects' properties to store some data such as several headings, etc

Comment: OK, that works, but I'm not sure how to count the subheadings, as this is being used to dynamically create a form... 

I'm not opposed to using arrays instead, but what I'm currently doing is calling to an API and using `json_decode` and it is putting in that format.

Comment: So, would you like to accept the answer then?