# How do I parse stdClass - php?

Tags: php, parsing, object, stdclass

When I do var_dump, I get the following result:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
    '0' =>
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'field' => 'name',
        'value' => 'John Smith',
        'description' => 'User full name',
    ))
))
```

I need the field, value & description in separate string vars.
**How do I do this?**

I tried:

```
$field = $obj->field;
$field = $obj->0->field;
$field = $obj->'0'->field;
$field = $obj[0]->field;
$field = $obj['0']->field;
```

Nothing works!?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access object properties with names like integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

Comment: Try `$obj->{'0'}->field;`.

Comment: And it's "traversing", not "parsing", if you already have an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the curly brace syntax to traverse the object, like so:

```
$obj->{'0'}->field;
$obj->{'0'}->value
$obj->{'0'}->description
```