# How can I get text from this in php?

Tags: php

I need to show only the status value of this string but I dont know how to do:

```
Web Object ( 
    [data] => stdClass Object ( 
        [operations] => stdClass Object ( 
            [384322232931] => stdClass Object ( 
                [status] => on
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [error] => 
)
```

Thanks for read

Comment: $something->data->operations->384322232931->status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the number `384322232931` is "random", if so, you'll have to use a recursive method:

```
function captureStatus($data) {
    $obj = (array) $data;
    $key = key($obj);

    if ($key === 'status') {
        return $obj['status'];
    } else if ($key !== NULL) {
        return captureStatus($obj[$key]);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

if not random, use the method of @Barmar

Answer (score 3):

If the object is in `$webobj`, it would be:

```
$webobj->data->operations->{'384322232931'}->status
```

You can't use normal property syntax when the property name is numeric, you need the braces and quotes, as described here: [How to access object properties with names like integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

If that number is the account ID, you can do:

```
$webobj->data->operations->{$account_id}->status
```

where `$account_id` contains your account number.

Comment: And if the {'384322232931'} is a random number?

Comment: Is this coming from JSON? It would probably be easier if you used `json_decode($json, true)` so you get an array instead of an object. Then you can use `foreach()` to iterate over all the elements of `operations`.

Comment: I get this response from this php sdk: https://github.com/ElevenPaths/latch-sdk-php from      $statusResponse = $api->status(ACCOUNT_ID_HERE);

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the property you want is embedded deeply, so the issue you're probably having is that you need to go through several children.

Try:
    $status = $yourObj->data->operations->384322232931->status;

I don't know if that helps. I'm a little confused what you mean by the "string" because what you posted looks like the print_r output for an object.

If what you're trying to do is extract that value from a string then I think you might be doing something wonky.

Comment: Yes, the data I post is the print_r output, sorry if I post the wrong data.