# PHP: access object with key int

Tags: php, json, object

I receive jsons in this format:

```
{"106371527":[33,22,11,2],"10003989":[3,2,11,3]}
```

note: 106371527,10003989 users ids

when I use json_decode(), still can't access data because the object keys is int,

how to fix this?

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access object properties with names like integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also be able to access the property by wrapping it in `{}`:

```
$json = '{"106371527":[33,22,11,2],"10003989":[3,2,11,3]}';
$object = json_decode($json);
print_r($object->{106371527});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer, use:

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

to return array rather than object,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

thanks,