# Push a single Object onto an array of Objects

Tags: php

I have the object below:

```
    $user= 
    object(stdClass)(2) 
    { 
        ["questions"]=> object(stdClass)(1) { [0] => object(stdClass) } 
        ["num_root_responses_for_section"]=> string(1) "0" 
    }
```

I want add an object so that I will have an array of objects into the questions property.

```
$user->questions[] = $new_question_object;
```

Doesn't work as it isn't an array.

I want something like so:

```
object(stdClass)(2) 
    { 
        ["questions"]=> object(stdClass)(2) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass), 
            [1]=> object(stdClass) }
        ["num_root_responses_for_section"]=> string(1) "0" 
    }
```

I understand that I can count it, increment the count, then add my object. Just looking for a better way.

Comment: If `questions` is an object, then it is not an array.  You would have to write some logic to determine the max property number/name that exists and then add 1.  You would be better using an array.

Comment: @allencoded Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10333016/3933332

Comment: It's not an array!  It is an object with numerical property names.

Comment: Bad use of a language isn't the same as a bad language.

Comment: Why not do all you need to do with it as an array first then convert your final array to an object?

Comment: So I already have an object. I have to convert that object into an array in order to push an object I have (which must also be converted into an array)  into it. Then I can take that array and cast it back to an object in order to get my object back. Sounds a little silly but I guess if it works.

Comment: `questions` shouldn't be an object in the first place.

Comment: Since you insist on using objects you can do this.. $users->questions->{'9'} = 'value'; where 9 in this case is your preferred index

Comment: So you gave up or what?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes I went with using arrays

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using an array, and this is hackish but I was bored:

```
$n = max(array_keys(get_object_vars($user->questions)));
$user->questions->{$n+1} = $new_question_object;
```

Or shorter (not really):

```
$user->questions->{max(array_keys(get_object_vars($user->questions)))+1} = $new_question_object;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you insist on using objects you can do this..

```
$users->questions->{'9'} = 'value';
```

where 9 in this case is your preferred index for that item.

Comment: yeah meaning I would have to count the objects and add 1

Comment: Yes. That's what you would have to do