# How to assign value of array to existing object property

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to assign value of array to existing object property. I tried this and got error.

```
 $fieldss = array("name"=>"User Name", "fields"=>"10091437300560754");

 $list = object(stdClass)[325]
   public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
   public 'form_id' => string '6' (length=1)
   public '10091437300560754' => string 'Ronaldo' (length=9)

 //then I tried to access:
 $list->$fieldss['fields'];    which equals to 'Ronaldo'.
 //but It gives undefined property:$10091437300560754;
```

Above:  `$fieldss['fields'] = "10091437300560754";` and `$list->$fieldss['fields']` means `$list->10091437300560754` but why I get undefined property. Please help.

### Updated

I tried my code in localhost with PHP v5.3.8 It worked fine But When I uploaded to server in which PHP v5.4. It gives me error like above

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers/10333200#10333200) is an explanation

Answer (score 0):

10091437300560754 is not a valid variable/property name. A valid variable name **starts with a letter or underscore**, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

Comment: If you can't change property name you can try: $list->{$fieldss['fields']}

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it's working fine at my end.

```
$fieldss = array("name" => "User Name", "fields" => "10091437300560754");

$list = (object) array('id' => '1',
            'form_id' => '6',
            '10091437300560754' => 'Ronaldo');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
//then I tried to access:
echo $list->$fieldss['fields'];
```

Comment: I tried my code in localhost with PHP v5.3.8 It worked fine But When I uploaded to server in which PHP v5.4. It gives me error like above.

Comment: Try this $test=$fieldss['fields'];
echo $list->$test;

Comment: No It didnot worked.  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array