# how to get objects of objects for an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => 
            [description] =>
        )
)
```

how can i get the description field in php

Comment: `$object->{1}->description` ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10333016/3933332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
foreach($parentObject as $childObject){
   echo $childObject->description;
   //or $childObject['description'] if childObject is array
}
```

Comment: did you tried my cod?if you did please give a feedback