# How to convert php object array from one form to another

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to convert an object array from this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title 1
            [1] => Title 2
            [2] => Title 3
            [3] => Title 4
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Description 1
            [1] => Description 2
            [2] => Description 3
            [3] => Description 4
        )

    [myimage] => Array
        (
            [0] => images/events/568a7048f22f9/sizes/athens-img_XS.jpg
            [1] => images/collections/56b2294894c08/islamiki.png
            [2] => images/multimedia/item6.jpg
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

To this:

```
stdClass Object
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 1
            [description] => Description 1
            [myimage] => images/events/568a7048f22f9/sizes/athens-img_XS.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 2
            [description] => Description 2
            [myimage] => images/collections/56b2294894c08/islamiki.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 3
            [description] => Description 3
            [myimage] => images/multimedia/item6.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 4
            [description] => Description 4
            [myimage] => 

        )
)
```

Comment: Take a look at [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: This is not relative. I dont think you even understood the question

Comment: Possibly. Would you like a code example? iteration and array_column is about the easiest way I can think of dealing with it.

Comment: Well you weren't weren't wrong, I indeed misunderstood. Assuming you want array for the conversion not object? I ask as [numeric object properties can cause real headaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/3672979).

Comment: I just asked how to convert one thing to another. Simple as that. Both are stdObject that hold the same information. Its just different structure of the representation of the same information. I was just thinking if there was an easy way instead of looping and reconstructing the object.

Comment: Fair enough, I can't come up with any way without looping and Ryan has you covered there :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is interesting...

Transpose a '2d matrix' - columns into rows. (Realized it did this - months after I wrote it)

- each output entry consists of an associated array:
- the key is the property names
- the data is the 'current column data' for that property

[Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/516552)

#### Demonstrations of using the function:

[1) Original data - call the function.... Eval.in](https://eval.in/517203)

Now, as long as the data is consistent, as regards number of properties and number of rows of data for each property:

You can change the data without having to change the code.

[Two extra properties to each entry and three extra entries... Eval.in](https://eval.in/517204)

#### The code:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// output in here...
$outArray = array();                         // (step 0)

$propsAsArray = get_object_vars($srcObject);  // (step 1) properties as an array

$rowKeys = array_keys($propsAsArray);         // (step 2) we need the the key names

for ($i = 0, $itemCount = count(current($propsAsArray)); $i < $itemCount; $i++) { // (step 3)

    $column = array_column($propsAsArray, $i); // (step 4) get one vertical column through al the arrays

    $entry = array_combine($rowKeys, $column); // (step 5)

    $outArray[] = $entry;                      // (step 6) 
}

$outArray = (object) $outArray;               // (step 7)
```

#### As a function:

```
function convertArray($srcObject) {
    $propsAsArray = get_object_vars($srcObject);  
    $rowKeys = array_keys($propsAsArray);         

    for ($i = 0, $itemCount = count(current($propsAsArray)); $i < $itemCount; $i++) { 

        $outArray[] = array_combine($rowKeys, 
                                    array_column($propsAsArray, $i)); 
    }

    return (object) $outArray;              
}
```

#### The output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 1
            [description] => Description 1
            [myimage] => images/events/568a7048f22f9/sizes/athens-img_XS.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 2
            [description] => Description 2
            [myimage] => images/collections/56b2294894c08/islamiki.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 3
            [description] => Description 3
            [myimage] => images/multimedia/item6.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Title 4
            [description] => Description 4
            [myimage] => 
        )
)
```

#### Explanation of the steps.

I will only comment the more `involved ones`.

*Step 1:*

We need the property names and data array as an `associated array` with the property name as the 'key' and the related data.

This is just a 2-dimensional array where the 'keys' are the original property names
and the data is an array of the values associated with that property.

*Step 2:*

Get the 'property names for each output entry'. These are the keys of the array from `step 1`.

There can be as many as you wish.

*Step3:*

This is where the work starts...

We are going to take `vertical slices` through the '2D array'. That is what `array_column` does.

We need to know how many `columns` of data that there actually are. However, it is an `associated array` and we don't know the key names.

Not an an issue:

The 'current function' return the value of the current entry of the `2D array`
Then just take count of that and store it.

I do it in the `initialization part of 'for' loop` for efficiency.

*Step 4:*

We need to get a `vertical slice` of the `current column ($i)` through the `2D array`.

*Step 5:*

We now have:

- a list of keys for the entry ($rowKeys)
- a data array where each entry matches with the corresponding 'property'

So make the entry and add it to output.

*Step 7:*

Convert the array back to a `stdClass` object.

Comment: All arrays are the same length indeed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I now need to explain what why the code works... :)

Comment: Neater than mine, +1

Comment: No its ok I understand the code. I am just thinking if there is any other easer way.

Comment: @themis, Maybe useful? You can add more property arrays without having to change the code as it doesn't use data array indexes anywhere.

Comment: Nice function but how would you really call this function? If you see those objects are actually the same information but in different structure.

Comment: @themis, examples of calling the function added - 1) original. 2) extra data. The code doesn't change.

Comment: I mean how would you "Name it" Because convertArray is totally abstract

Comment: `convertArray` is a function that you can call from anywhere. Please check the 'eval.in' links to the code that calls the function.