# Working with PHP objects that contain numerical property names

Tags: php, json, object

This seems like it should be simple but I just can't get it to work. I'm working working with a massive PHP object that contains sports teams' data.  The portion of this object I'm having trouble with is as follows:

```
    [team] => stdClass Object
    (
        [296] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 296
                [name] => Home Team
                [abbreviation] => HOME
            )

        [193] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 193
                [name] => Away Team
                [abbreviation] => AWAY
            )

    )
```

Being that there are multiple matches with multiple teams, each with their own unique ID number, how can I dynamically match the number (not the `[id]`) that corresponds to each team? In other words, instead of writing `team->296->name`, how can I write it like `team->$team_id->name`?

I can't seem to find a solution that works.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/3859027

Comment: Why are you doing these as objects instead of associative arrays?

Comment: In order to retrieve the data I'm using `file_get_contents` as the data is hosted on one of our other servers.