# PHP: Getting associative array returns null, despite existing in var_dump

Tags: php, arrays, json, null

I have an array of 'servers' that I'm storing in a JSON file.

The JSON file looks like this:
`{"1":{"available":1,"players":0,"maxplayers":4}}`

I retrieve this value with this:

```
$servers = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents("activeservers.json"));
```

However, when I try to access the array with `$server = $servers[$id]`, `$server` is null. I noticed that the key is in quotes, so I also tried casting `$id` to a string, and surrounding it with quotes (") which didn't work.

Something to note, is that this code is returning "NULL":

```
foreach(array_keys($servers) as $key){
    var_dump($servers[$key]);
}
```

Comment: `$servers[$id]` doesn't exist in you json. Where is the 'id' key in the json?

Comment: Instead of type casting just pass TRUE as second parameter to `json_decode()`

Comment: `$id` is the key. @bos570

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123

Comment: Yes, you're using it as a key but where are you setting value for $id?

Comment: @SamMearns You might want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200 to understand a bit better why it is so "weird" and your method didn't work properly.

Comment: Thanks very much @Rizier123

Comment: You do not have an `id` you just have occurance 1 of an array

Comment: @RiggsFolly The `id` is the key to the sub-array

Comment: For example, with two servers: `{"1":{"available":1,"players":0,"maxplayers":4},"2":{"available":1,"players":0,"maxplayers":4}}`

Comment: @bos570 in the `GET` request. - A list of servers is displayed to the end user who then selects one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @Rizier123 (who solved the question).

Apparently passing `TRUE` as the second parameter to my `json_decode` function fixes the issue.

After checking the PHP documentation for `json_decode()` ([PHP: json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)), it seems that passing this parameter means that the resulting decoded array is automatically converted into an associative array (and this is recurring, meaning that this automatically happens for sub-arrays).

Edit: @Rizier123 also says that "*you might want to read: stackoverflow.com/a/10333200 to understand a bit better why it is so "weird" and your method didn't work properly.*"

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong. Also you don't need to type cast when doing a `json_decode`, you can instead set the second parameter to true more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
Also you don't need to use the `array_keys` function in your foreach loop, 
try this.

```
$json    = '{"1":{"available":1,"players":0,"maxplayers":4}}';
$servers = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($servers as $key => $value) {
    print $value["available"];
}
```

Do a `print_r($value)` to get all the array keys available to use. Also you could take advantage of the `$key` variable to print out the array key of the parent array.

Comment: Why print over echo?

Comment: Its just a matter of preference. The differences are small: echo has no return value while print has a return value of 1 so it can be used in expressions.

Comment: FYI: The foreach loop was just to demonstrate my point and wouldn't be used in production.

Comment: @SamMearns it doesn't change the fact your code was incorrect.

Comment: Only the lack of the `TRUE` parameter?

Comment: No, you were using array_keys on the foreach loop when it is pointless.

Comment: Yes I understand it but it is still pointless using it. Because the `var_dump($servers[$key]);` you're referencing is not the `array_keys($servers)` in your foreach loop. To prove my point is you do this `foreach($test_servers = array_keys($servers) as $value) { print $test_servers[$value]; }` your code will break.  Am on this because I don't think you understood the use of array_keys, otherwise you would not use it even if it was for demonstration purposes. Am not picking on you by the way.