# Using a invalid attribute name

Tags: php

Should this even be possible?

```
$array = ['1invalidName'];
$object = new \stdClass();
$object->{$array[0]} = 200;

var_dump($object);
```

`$object->1invalidName` is a syntax error, only way to retrieve the value is through `$object->{$array[0]}` again.

Comment: Because variable can't start with a number.

Comment: But shouldn't that apply to object attributes too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties with names like integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

Comment: It does that's why you can't use `1invalidName`.  `{$array[0]}` is just faking it out.  I think `$object->{'1invalidName'}` will work as well.