# How to select integer from an object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I know it's probably a dumb question but I'm unable to go over this.

I have this Object array which looks like this

```
stdClass Object
(
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Product] => Brand Manual
        [Type] => Custom
        [Width_(inches)] => 11
        [Depth_(inches)] => 8.5
        [Color_Type] => B/W
        [Artistic_Discretion] => Full Artistic Discretion(AD3)
        [Brief/Instructions] => edasd
         Product Dimension - 8.5" x 11"

        [Copy_Translation] => No
        [Additional_Versions] => 0
    )
 )
```

I want the `Brand Manual` so I do this `$myValue = $myObject->1->Product;` It doesn't work. The integer '1' seems to be the problem. I tried adding quotes too but it doesn't work either.Please help.

Comment: don't give integer keys to your objects

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest im getting this object from a web service so I dont have control over it. any way out?

Comment: [refer to this great post for well undestanding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10333016/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$myValue = $myObject->{1}->Product;
```

Comment: Who now :) property_exists($obj, "2") return false; Maybe any internal php error.

Answer (score 2):

If your object variable is not cast from an array, you can access such properties with curly brace syntax.

```
$myObject->{'1'}->Product;
```

I strongly reconmend you read this great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

You have data stored in object format, so you should use object notation to get your specific data as

```
$myValue = $myObject->{1}->Product;
```