# In Laravel 5, what does this do: $this->{$var}

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code in an api endpoint, which checks there are no relationships on a model to be deleted (and returns true to show it's in use):

CONTROLLER

```
public function destroy(Group $group)
    {
        if ($group->inUse()) {
            return response(
                ['message' => 'This group cannot be deleted because it has either associated 
                catalogue items, users or organisations'],
                409
            );
        }

        $group->delete();
    }
```

MODEL

```
public function inUse()
{
    $models = [
        'categories',
        'items',
        'organisations',
    ];

    foreach ($models as $model) {
        if (count($this->{$model}) > 0 ){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The line which I don't fully understand is where we check the number of relations for each model: `count($this->{$model})`

[I read on php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) that $this->{$var} is a variable variable, but that can't be the case here, the first run through of the loop would return an undefined variable $categories:

```
if($this->$categories) {
    //
}
```

Is this a laravel feature or special syntax? I did a quick search but nothing came up I could see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did you find this code?

Comment: You can read about it here: [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: @Remul This is string interpolation and I believe it is something slightly different.

Comment: @DejavuGuy it was in a codebase I am working on - I sanitised/changed it to hide the business critical info.

Comment: I agree its not exactly what your looking for, but its the only mention of accessing object properties with curly braces on the php.net site that I could find. You can read more about in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/9193055) .

Comment: @Remul yeah my bad, I was totally getting mixed up there, you were right about the brackets!

Answer (score 5):

Its php syntax, curly brackets used to call object properties dynamically, in your case this will be translated as:

`if (count($this->categories) > 0 )`, `if (count($this->items) > 0 )` ...

Comment: I read $this->{$var} as $this->${$var} - this was what was confusing me!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling property on the given model - by the look of it represented by the relationship as you're checking for the number of records.

I believe your `$models` variable contains names of the relationships
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Checking for `count` would suggest they return instance of the `Collection` and you could probably just use `$this->{$model}->count()` or `$this->{$model}->isEmpty()`.

The curly braces in your example are optional and both of these are equivalent:

```
$this->{$model}
$this->$model
```

Same as using curly braces with strings:

```
"Some text {$array[0]}"
```

These are not variable variables - as documentation states

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as
>   the name of a variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I thought the curly brackets in $this->{$var} meant a variable variable - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

I would expect this to return an undefined variable error.

Comment: They would be if you included `$` before the brackets and used it as a reference to the variable i.e. `${$var}`, but you're referring to the internal property of the given object `$this->{$var}` is equivalent of `$this->$var` - just a little syntax sugar with the brackets in this case.

Comment: Thanks - I think that is what I tripping up on!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here, first, it defines an array that list the relationships to check:

```php
$models = [
    'categories',
    'items',
    'organisations',
];
```

Then, it loop this array to check that at least one of this relations has elements:

```php
foreach ($models as $model) {
    if (count($this->{$model}) > 0 ){
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, if we take the first element of the array:

```php
echo $models[0] // 'categories'
```

in the validation:

```php
foreach ($models as $model) {
    // in this case, $model is 'categories'
    // now it check if the relationship has elements:
    // the following is equivalent to: if(count($this->{$model} > 0) {
    if (count($this->categories) > 0 ){
        return true;
    }
}
...
```