# How can I return the count value from below array

Tags: php, sql

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fruit] => apple
            [COUNT(form_value)] => 8
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fruit] => apple
            [COUNT(form_value)] => 5
        )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object properties with names like integers or invalid property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers-or-invalid-property-nam)

Comment: Also you can add __alias__ to `COUNT(form_value)` in your sql query

Comment: To explain @u_mulders comment. If you do `SELECT COUNT(form_value) FROM table` the key of the result will be _COUNT(form_value)_. If you do `SELECT COUNT(form_value) AS form_value FROM table` the key will be _form_value_

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can rename the COUNT(form_value) in your SQL Query. For example use:

```
SELECT COUNT(form_value) AS form_value_count FROM %your_table_name%
```

To get all counts from you array, you can use (if you change your SQL-query):

```
foreach(%your_array_variable% AS $d){
    echo $d['form_value_count'];
}
```