# Json_Decode With a int as a name

Tags: php, json

ok,  so I have a Huge JSON feed,
And all is working well.  Exept,  one of the key

Curently I am doing

```
$json=file_get_contents($source);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($data->items->features as $a){
   echo "{$a->properties->tpegMessage->generation_time_pretty}\n";
   echo '<br />';
   echo "{$a->properties->tpegMessage->title}\n";
   echo '<br />';
   echo "{$a->properties->geometry->coordinates->1}\n";
   echo '<br />';
   echo "{$a->properties->geometry->coordinates->0}\n";
   echo '<br />';   echo '<br />';   echo '<br />';   echo '<br />';   echo '<br />';
}
```

Now the key issue is with

''$a->properties->geometry->coordinates->0''

As php wont retrave the JSON value with the 0 or 1 name

the values are typicaly floats,  value to a lat or long.

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240532/how-can-i-access-an-object-attribute-that-starts-with-a-number or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851489/return-php-object-by-index-number-not-name

Comment: Cheers This is exacly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$a->properties->geometry->coordinates->{0}
```

In case of echo:

```
echo $a->properties->geometry->coordinates->{0} . "\n";
```