# Accessing Object with Key as Number PHP

Tags: php, oop, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [page] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [element] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [background_color] => stdClass Object
...
```

And when I print `print_r($arr->page)`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [element] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [background_color] => stdClass Object
                        (
```

But this prints nothing:

```
print_r($arr->page->{"1"});
```

And this prints an error:

```
print_r($arr->page->1);
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' i

How can I access the "1" element?

UPDATE:

I've also tried `$arr->page[1]` and `$arr->page["1"]` but get this error:

> Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

UPDATE 2:

```
var_dump($arr->page);
```

prints this:

```
 object(stdClass)#3 (1) {   [1]=>   
   object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
     ["element"]=>
     object(stdClass)#5 (20) {
       ["background_color"]=>
       object(stdClass)#6 (7) {
```

Comment: Sorry but I have tried that answer as my question shows, it's not working for me, any ideas of why it wouldn't?

Comment: `var_dump($arr->page->{'1'})` prints `NULL`

Comment: Thanks for your input Jack, see the correct answer for more info.

Comment: I just started working within a large application, I need to modify some values inside the object. I'm not sure where or how it's created. But I will learn more as I dig deeper.

Comment: Yes, that prints `NULL` with `var_dump`

Comment: For those interested in reproducing this issue, use this: `$arr = (object)['page' => (object)[1 => (object)['element' => 'hello world']]];`

Comment: I think you can try: (string)$arr->page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot access integer class variables directly. The best option is to not use StdClass at all.

If you cannot control the source of your data, you can cast to an array via `$foo = (array) $foo`.

You can also iterate over the elements:

```
foreach ($obj as $key=>$val)
```

Or

```
foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $key => $val)
```

Comment: Wow really, I didn't know that, I did not vote you down, I'll try to cast and the foreach

Comment: It works! Thanks I'll have to remember this, just to clarify I used your first example there `foreach ($obj as $key=>$val)` and `$val->element` gave me access, thanks again!

Comment: @Jack, good point. I've removed that bit from the answer. I think I was remembering times when I've dealt with sketchy libraries that blindly cast API results into an object for no good reason.

Comment: Are you saying there was a time before `json_decode()`? *gasp* :)

Answer (score 28):

Use quotes:

```
print_r($arr->page->{'1'});
```

From here: [How can I access an object attribute that starts with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240532/how-can-i-access-an-object-attribute-that-starts-with-a-number?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry this prints nothing for me? single or double quotes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php/3446286#3446286 for the difference between single and double quotes in PHP.

Comment: This only works for string keys `"1"` vs `int(1)`. If an object was created by "illegal" means, then you cannot access the integer keys like this.