# How to create an object with number properties?

Tags: php, oop

I need to know is there a way to create an object with properties with number instead of names in php, so I can get them like this:

```
$property = $obj->{1}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159295/accessing-object-with-key-as-number-php

Comment: I think you can try this by making your class implement  ArrayAccess. Never tried it though. But honestly speaking, just don't do this. Object properties need to be descriptive. Having them as numbers doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, working with a JSON and want to retrieve data based on its index? For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606340/get-a-php-object-property-that-is-a-number

Comment: Also see this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/10333016/296555

Comment: maybe is my preference, but I find it much better to go for named properties. Makes the usage clearer and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Er... Yes, you can. It's the very same syntax you are already using:

```
$obj = (object)nuLL;
$obj->{1} = 'Hi!';
var_dump($obj);
```

([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CVdJ9))

Answer (score 0):

U can't set name property of object as integer .
If you want iterate properties

```
get_object_vars($object);
```